# pandas set single row value based on condition (not multiple rows)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that consists of multiple units, and each unit has multiple cycles, and each cycle has multiple rows. I need to create a column within each unit-cycle combo that goes from 0 to 1, that tells us our time in the cycle on any row. The best thing I have came up with is a nested for loop and this condition

```
df.loc[(df.asset_id == unit) & (df.cycle == cycle), 'time']
```

The length of the cycle is given by

```
length = len(df[(df.asset_id == unit) & (df.cycle == cycle)])
```

and the 'time' value is given in a for loop over the rows by

```
row/length
```

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to assign this value to each row individually. Everything I find online works for multiple rows, but I need this on a per-row basis.

This works but is incorrect for what I need to do

```
df.loc[(df.asset_id == unit) & (df.cycle == cycle), 'time'] = row/length
```

These do not work but is what I need

```
df.loc[(df.asset_id == unit) & (df.cycle == cycle), 'time'].iloc[row] = row/length
df.loc[(df.asset_id == unit) & (df.cycle == cycle), 'time'][row] = row/length
```

Thanks in advance. I also suspect there is a more efficient way to do this as well.

Comment: What does your dataframe look like? Can you show us the table itself?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

While this technically doesn't answer my question, it solves my problem. Instead of assigning individual values to individual rows, I assign an array of values to a set of rows.

```
for unit in pd.unique(units.id):
    for cycle in pd.unique(df[df.asset_id == unit].cycle):
        length = len(df[(df.asset_id == unit) & (df.cycle == cycle)])
        x = np.arange(0, length)/(length-1)
        df.loc[(df.asset_id == unit) & (df.cycle == cycle), 'time'] = x
```